# What does "View and manage your mail" in Google permissions mean?

Tags: gmail, permissions, oauth

View mail is something I would like to give to this app -- but what the heck is manage?

Comment: what application are you talking about?

Comment: slice.com but the permission is presented by google.com when authenticating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the ability to "manage" (and not just "view") your GMail includes the various actions that you might perform manually when interacting with your account via the standard web-interface.  For example, such actions can include deleting, starring, labeling, and archiving individual emails -- to name just a few.

I personally do not use [Slice.com](http://slice.com), and so I don't know for sure which exact actions it needs in order to function properly.  However, I can imagine how it might need more than just "view" permissions.